# Django 2.0 Block/Force Particular Browser

Tags: python, django

In my new Django project, i am planning to use CSS Grid for template layout. To make site responsive without using bootstrap. So here i want to know how can i block those browser which doesn't support CSS grid ??

For testing purpose i tried this in **settings.py** but nothing works

```
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = (re.compile(r'IE\s[0-9]+', re.IGNORECASE), )
```

is there any better way to do this ? 
where i can force user to upgrade their browser

Comment: I tried one more time  and now it's working for old IE (Trident),  now tell me how to response with page like "Upgrade your browser" ?  [See this image](http://outdatedbrowser.com/public/files/pics/outdated-social.jpg)
   
 `DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = (re.compile(r'Trident+', re.IGNORECASE), )`

Comment: I thought User Agent string cannot be modify but later i found many add-ons which can tweak User Agent string easily . So is there any safe way to query browser and other detail in Django or Python ?